# Windows Terminal Paste Pre-Defined Text via Custom Key Bind

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-terminal

I copy and paste different sets of pre-defined text often, so it would be nice to have a program-level key bind to set this. In the .json file key bindings section, I have tried things like:

```
{
  "command": {
    "command": "paste",
    "insert": "<custom txt",
    "keys": "ctrl+s"
  }
  
}
```

or

```
{
      "command": {
        "command": "paste",
        "commandline": "custom txt",
      }
      "keys": "ctrl+s"
    }
```

.

There appears to be no action set for this in the available [Windows Terminal key binding doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings).

Answer (score 0):

[Send input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#send-input): *Send arbitrary text input to the shell.*

Add the following item in the `keybindings` (or `actions`) array:

```
// Press Ctrl+S to send text (defined by the "input" field) to the shell.
// This command is not currently bound in the default settings.
{ "command": { "action": "sendInput", "input": "some custom text" }, "keys": "ctrl+s" }
```

> **ⓘ  Important**
>
> As of Windows Terminal version 1.4, the `keybindings` array has been
> renamed to `actions` inside the *settings.json* file. Support for the
> `keybindings` array still exists for backward compatibility, however
> the terminal will not automatically rename `keybindings` to `actions`
> inside your *settings.json* file.